# Would springs or rubber bands provide the most protection?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces

Currently designing a construction for an egg drop challenge. The egg will be dropped from a height of ~8 meters. I am planning to construct a skeleton around the egg and then use rubberbands or springs to support the egg in the middle. The egg itself will be put in a 3D-printed container to fit its shape. Here is an undetailed drawing:
[image: Undetailed scetch]

I have not decided on what shape the skeleton should actually be yet. But was contemplating using rubber bands or springs for supporting the egg itself.
I have read [this thread](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/311527/why-do-springs-and-rubber-bands-obey-hookes-law-differently) about springs actually having more elastic capacity. Would that mean strings to be the better option? If the difference is not too big, I would rather use rubber bands because of their lighter weight.

This may seem like an engineering question, but I am interested in why one option would be better than the other.

Answer (score 1):

Rubber bands will only cushion the egg when in tension, so you will have to pre-tension them - which means working out how to attach them to the egg in some way. Springs will cushion the egg in both tension and compressions, so you can just rest the springs against the egg - but springs are generally stiffer than rubber bands and so may provide less cushioning for the egg (for ideal cushioning you want the egg to move as far as possible without hitting the ground or the cage). As you say, there is also a weight trade off - if there is a weight limit on the task then springs may be too heavy.

The best approach is an empirical one - run tests with both springs and rubber bands to see which one works best. You could also try different shapes for the cage - for example, a tetrahedron cage could be lighter than a cubic cage, while providing just as much cushioning.